# Can Tether Essence be used to heal Undead?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, undead, healing

The *tether essence* spell states:

> Two creatures [...] are magically linked for the duration, regardless of the distance between them. When damage is dealt to one of them, the same damage is dealt to the other one. If hit points are restored to one of them, the same number of hit points are restored to the other one. [...]

Meanwhile several healing spells cannot affect Undead, for example, *healing word*:

> [...] This spell has no effect on undead or constructs. [...]

But what happens when an Undead and a non-Undead are linked together and *healing word* is used on the non-Undead individual. Obviously, they would heal, but what about the linked Undead; do they heal as well?

Answer (score 3):

#### Yes, the healing applies to both creatures.

*Tether essence* makes no creature type distinctions. Further, *it makes no distinctions about the source of the healing*. It only states:

> If hit points are restored to one of them, the same number of hit points are restored to the other one.

So if we have a human and an undead linked by *tether essence*, any hitpoints restored to the human by any method will restore hitpoints to the undead. And to be precise, *the undead creature is healed by the effect of tether essence, not the effect that heals the human*, so even if the human is healed by an effect that cannot affect undead, the undead still receives healing.